# Java Reading File

Tags: java

i am reading csv file.and in that i have created 2 methods 1)getHeaders and 2)getContent so assuming 1 line as a header file i am take 1 line in header and storing in one variable and hence when i am reading again that file i am not getting the expected output.

```
public static String getHeaderLine(File file) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String headerLine = reader.readLine();
    return headerLine;  
}

public void convertCSVtoJSON() throws IOException {
    File f = new File("C:\\user\\Desktop\\Abc.csv");
    String headerLine = CSVtoJSON.getHeaderLine(f);
    System.out.println(getHeaderLine(f));

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    while (in.readLine() != null) {
        System.out.println(in.readLine());
    }
}
```

Abc.csv:

```
name,add,sal
john,SF,25k
Roy,Chicago,30k
jason,SF,35k
joy,Sf,50K
```

Output:

```
name,add,sal
john,SF,25k
jason,SF,35k
null
```

Expected output:

```
name,add,sal
john,SF,25k
Roy,Chicago,30k
jason,SF,35k
joy,Sf,50K
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: Please don't use `File` anymore. Instead use the new modern **NIO** API of Java which revolves around the classes `Paths`, `Files` and `Path`. With it you'll shrink your method to 1-2 lines. Also you should **never forget** to **close** your resources. Use `reader.close()` and `in.close()` if you are finished reading.

Comment: @Zabuza thanks for responding.and its been verified code you can also check by running the same..it gives the same output as i have shown..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

It is because you use `readLine` to check whether there is something to read and then again use `readLine` inside the loop.

So you actually read a line, reject it (inside the condition) and then read **again** a line. So every iteration you are reading **two** lines but only print **one** and you also only check for `null` with **one** of those **two** lines. That is why you see the print of `null` in the last iteration since there is no line left.

Considering your example:

```
name,add,sal     // $1
john,SF,25k      // $2
Roy,Chicago,30k  // $3
jason,SF,35k     // $4
joy,Sf,50K       // $5
```

And your code:

```
System.out.println(getHeaderLine(f));   // #1
while (in.readLine() != null) {         // #2
    System.out.println(in.readLine());  // #3
}
```

Line `#1` reads the head line `$1` and **prints it**.

Then you create a new `BufferedReader` whose pointer is placed at the start of the file again, so the head line. Line `#2` is executed which again reads the head line `$1` and checks it for `null`. It is not `null` and the code starts the first loop iteration.

Line `#3` is executed, reading and **printing** the **second line** `$2`. The loop checks again the condition in line `#2`, it reads the next line `$3` and checks it for `null`.

It's not and line `#3` gets executed which reads and **prints line** `$4`. The condition is checked again in line `#2`, thus it reads line `$5` and checks it for `null`. It is again not `null` thus it continues.

Again line `#3` is executed which reads and **prints a line** (`$6`). However as there is no line left anymore to read, it reads and prints `null`. The condition is checked again, trying to read a line (`$7`) but there is no, the loop terminates.

All in all we have printed line `$1` (due to `#1`) and `$2`, `$4`, `null` (due to `#3`):

```
name,add,sal   // $1
john,SF,25k    // $2
jason,SF,35k   // $4
null           // ($6)
```

Which is exactly what you got.

---

### Solution

You need to fix your logic. If you want to check whether there is something to read, don't read it, just check for it. Or alternatively read it, store it inside a variable and then check this variable.

```
while (true) {
    // Read a line
    String line = in.readLine();
    if (line == null) {
        // Abort, nothing to read anymore
        break;
    }

    // Print what we have read
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

---

### Modern solution: NIO

However I recommend you to not use `BufferedReader` and this stuff for reading files anymore. Java has updated its I/O API, we now use **NIO** which revolves around the classes `Path`, `Paths` and `Files`. With **NIO** you print every line **elegantly and platform independent** like this:

```
Path fileToRead = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop", "Abc.csv");
Files.lines(fileToRead).forEach(System.out::println);
```

That's all. `Path` substitutes the old `File` class. `Paths` and `Files` provide utility methods. Here are their documentations:

- [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)
- [Paths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html)
- [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hasNext()` to check if the input has a next line, then `next()` to print each line

Note: you should probably use a bit of `try-catch` in this to check the file exists etc

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\user\\Desktop\\Abc.csv"));
String headerLine = scanner.next();
//this now has the first line in 'headerLine'
System.out.print(headerLine);
System.out.print(" ");
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.print(scanner.next() + " ");
}
scanner.close();
```